# Journey Builder - Exit Criteria vs Exclusion Script

Tags: journeybuilder, exclusion-script

This is more of a logic check to see that I understand the differences between using exit criteria or exclusion script. Essentially I'm trying to find the most suitable way of excluding a set of customers on a journey (this would be for 1 day then they would need to be re-included). Trying to understand all the available options first.

**Exit Criteria** - Used to exit contacts when goals are met or on specific filters. (Can't be used if you want to exclude 10000 email addresses). Or more correctly, it can be used but that would create a complicated filter.

**Exclusion Script** - Used when you want to exclude contacts from Journey B that are included in Journey A, or when you want to exclude 10000 email addresses that you have stored in a Data extension?

A Third option could be to use a decision split in the journey to exit the 10000, but this would require setting up a data extension in data designer so that the attribute is available in Journey Builder?

Are there any options that I have missed? (apart from the obvious which would be to make sure we segment correctly for that day and don't have to exclude anyone)

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use automation as the journey entry so that you can run SQL/script activities before they are injected. The SQL/script activities can be edited pretty easily via APIs. The downside is that there will be another schedule to be managed. However, I think you can work around the automation schedule by triggering the automation programmatically.